# How to fix 'backgroundColor' error on app load in expo

Tags: android, react-native, fonts, expo

I am using expo v32. My app was running fine, next day when i run my expo app it won't launch, it is giving me the error related to 'backgroundColor', but not showing the location where it occurs.

I am trying to debug the error, but unable to do so. When i enable the 'Remotely debug JS' option the will crash after 100% loading. 
I was trying to debug code with console log, while debugging i found that code will run fine before the Font.loadasync function call, but after the function call the promise will not resolved and also doesn't throw any exception in try catch block.

```
async componentDidMount() {
        try {
            console.log("before font") // this will execute
            await Font.loadAsync({
                Roboto: require('native-base/Fonts/Roboto.ttf'),
                Roboto_medium: require('native-base/Fonts/Roboto_medium.ttf')
            });
            console.log("after font") // this will not execute
        } catch(e) {
            console.log("error", e) // this will not execute
        }
        this.setState({ fontLoaded: true })
    }
```

App should launch the page, but App is throwing error of some 'backgroundColor' and also the app should console the "after font" or "error" message but it didn't console any thing after "before font".[Error image of expo client app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oL4fQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an issue with the latest expo client. Try looking for anywhere you're using `backgroundColor` with any sort of transparency and remove the transparency.

https://forums.expo.io/t/error-with-last-expo-client-and-sdk32/23334